# Visual Studio 2012 express debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

could you tell me why this happens when I simply press F5 in order to start debugging? VS is freshly installed and  can't run hello world program :( 
I checked for c# console application and that module works, only problem is when choosing C++
here is the screenshot..
http://s50.radikal.ru/i129/1310/c5/ee67bc538bec.png

Comment: Did you build the program before you started debugging it? I dont see why you would be debugging it anyways. Building actually compiles the exe while debugging just steps through the program as it runs to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, i would recommend to `Clean` the project and choose `Rebuild`.
If the problem is still there, you need to check the `exe` location, and try to execute it manually.

I would say that the error is likely to come from some changes you did (project configuration) that require you to `clean` the solution, but it is just a mere guess.